# gdal_merge - creating intermittent (null seams) in mosaics

Tags: gdal

I’m supporting the web services development at [Geoscience Australia's Digital Earth Australia (DEA) project](http://www.ga.gov.au/about/projects/geographic/digital-earth-australia)

The DEA landsat coverage for Australia is stored as  > 1400  1 degree tiles in an Australian Albers projection.

Mosaicked together a 3 band byte file is > 112 GB.  Its a big data set and there are multiple continental products to be published.

We’ve been using the [NCI](http://nci.org.au/) to process these data – and have run into problems creating national mosaics and pyramids for our web services products.

We originally found that running ‘retile’ on the full national mosaic was taking > 14 hours on the NCI - and it becomes very unstable when rendering the higher resolution pyramids and crashes more often than not.

So as an alternative workflow .. we moved to a processing model based 16 degree processing blocks across the continent.

[image: 16 degree tile blocks]

Using these tile groups we use ;

- Gdal_buildvrt (used to create a virtual mosaic)

  ```
       *gdal_buildvrt(l_vrPathName,l_targetDir):
      cmd = r'gdalbuildvrt ' + l_vrPathName + ' ' + l_targetDir + '/*.tif'**
  ```
- Gdal_translatefiles (create a byte precision mosaic)

  ```
      *gdal_translateFiles(l_vrPathName,l_inputEPSG,l_tempPathName):
      cmd = r'gdal_translate --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 500 -a_srs "' +     l_inputEPSG + '" -scale 0 4095 0 255 -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 ' + '-of GTiff ' + '-ot Byte ' + '-co "TILED=YES" ' + '-co "BLOCKXSIZE=512" ' + '-co "BLOCKYSIZE=512" ' + l_vrPathName + ' ' + l_tempPathName*
  ```
- Gdal_warp (reprojects mosaic to wgs84 geographic’s)

  ```
     *gdal_warp(l_tempPathName,l_inputEPSG,l_destinationPathName):
     cmd = r'gdalwarp -r ' + g_samplingMethod + ' -srcnodata ' + g_srcNoData + '-of GTiff -multi --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 500 -wm 500 -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -s_srs ' + l_inputEPSG + ' -t_srs "' + g_outputEPSG + '" ' + l_tempPathName + ' ' + l_destinationPathName*
  ```
- Gdal_retile ( creates 7 layer pyramid structure)

  ```
        *gdal_retile(l_destinationDir, l_destinationPathName ):
        cmd = r'gdal_retile.py -v -r near -ps 2048 2048 -levels 7 -pyramidOnly -co "TILED=YES" -co "COMPRESS=LZW" -targetDir ' + l_destinationDir + ' ' + l_destinationPathName*
  ```
- Gdal_merge (creates mosaics from pyramid structure)

  ```
      *gdal_merge(mosfile, in_list):
     cmd = r'gdal_merge.py -n 0 -v -o ' + mosfile + ' --optfile ' + ' ' + in_list*
  ```

This model proved quite fast as it lent itself to parallel processing and is very stable.

**BUT** what we are found is that ‘merge’ is creating small intermittent seams (no data) between the tile blocks.

For testing I ran a workflow with a full 1 degree overlap between the tile blocks .. but the seams (albeit more intricate) still persist.

[image: seams around areas of overlap]

I suspect the gdal_warp is the initial source of the problem .. but the coverage is so large using the australian albers projection in geoserver just doesn't work.

Try as I might - I can't find a gdalwarp command line structure using; -tr -tap  that works!?

gdal_merge (in its current form),  works only on the neat lines of the input tiles and ignores any areas of overlap.

Question 1 : Is there a gdal mosaicing pathway that supports 'feathering' or a NN mapping in areas of overlap ?

I'd welcome any comments or suggestions on an alternative gdal workflow.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: Have you been running gdalwarp for the blocks with -tap for target aligned pixels?

Comment: @SomeGuy can you edit your question and include the command line args for your gdal* commands. Particularly gdawarp